# Linker issue when adding parameters to OpenCL project functions

Tags: c++, opencl, clr

I made an C++ OpenCL project used to process some code on a GPU. I need to access this project in C#, so naturally I am using a C#/CLR project to link both C# and C++ code.

The following code works when no argument is passed and doesn't work when I add some parameters:

Works:

CLI:

ClassLibrary1.cpp:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "ClassLibrary1.h"
#include "../OpenCLProject1/OpenCL.h"

namespace ClassLibrary1
{
    int Class1::Method(int value1, int value2)
    {
        OpenCL::TestMethod();
        return 0;  
    }
}
```

ClassLibrary1.h:

```
using namespace System;
namespace ClassLibrary1 {

    public ref class Class1
    {
        public:
            static int Method(int value1, int value2);
    };
}
```

OpenCL:

OpenCL.cpp:

```
#include "OpenCL.h"
void OpenCL::TestMethod()
{

}
```

OpenCL.h:

```
class OpenCL
{
    public:
        static void TestMethod();
};
```

Does not work:

CLI:

ClassLibrary1.cpp:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "ClassLibrary1.h"
#include "../OpenCLProject1/OpenCL.h"

namespace ClassLibrary1
{
    int Class1::Method(int value1, int value2)
    {
        return OpenCL::TestMethod(value1, value2); 
    }
}
```

ClassLibrary1.h:

```
using namespace System;
namespace ClassLibrary1 {

    public ref class Class1
    {
        public:
            static int Method(int value1, int value2);
    };
}
```

OpenCL:

OpenCL.cpp:

```
#include "OpenCL.h"
int OpenCL::TestMethod(int value1, int value2)
{
    return value1 + value2;
}
```

OpenCL.h:

```
class OpenCL
{
    public:
        static int TestMethod(int value1, int value2);
};
```

I get nice LNK2019 and LNK2028 errors:

```
ClassLibrary1.obj : error LNK2028: jeton non rÚsolu (0A000005) "public: static int __cdecl OpenCL::TestMethod(int,int)" (?TestMethod@OpenCL@@$$FSAHHH@Z) rÚfÚrencÚ dans la fonction "public: static int __clrcall ClassLibrary1::Class1::Method(int,int)" (?Method@Class1@ClassLibrary1@@$$FSMHHH@Z)
```

I am using Visual Studio 2015 Pro on Windows 10 b1903.

Comment: Why do you call `OpenCL::TestMethod` with Datatypes ?

Comment: Because I made a mistake while writing my issue on StackOverflow ^^